# Marquee direction 'up' will always pause for at least 2 seconds on the first item

Tags: jquery

When I use the direction 'up' I noticed that everytime the first item is scrolling upwards the scrolling will pause for at least 1-2 seconds and it happens on the succeeding loops. I tried this on IE, Firefox and chrome and the behavior is the same.

The scrolling should not pause at all. It should scroll continuously.

Here is my sample html.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html >
    <head>
        <title>News Ticker Demo</title>
        <style type="text/css">      
            BODY {BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FFF; COLOR: #000;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:0.75em;}
            #NewsTickerItems{border:1px solid black;padding:1px;}

            .latestnews .NewsItem{margin-top:30px;margin-left:10px;}
            .latestnews #NewsTickerItems {height: 105px;overflow: hidden;margin-top:10px;}
            .latestnews{padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.marquee.js"></script>                        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="latestnews">
            <div id='NewsTickerItems'>
                <div class="NewsItem">
                    <b>10/10/2014</b> 
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
                </div>
                <div class="NewsItem">
                    <b>10/10/2014</b> 
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
                </div>
                <div class="NewsItem">
                    <b>10/10/2014</b> 
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#NewsTickerItems').marquee({
                    //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
                    speed: 4000,
                    //gap in pixels between the tickers
                    delayBeforeStart: 0,
                    //'left' or 'right' or 'up' or 'down'
                    direction: 'up',
                    //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
                    duplicated: false,
                    //on hover pause the marquee
                    pauseOnHover: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would you like to try with HTML5 marquee?
HTML:

```
<marquee direction="up" id="myMarquee">This is a marquee.</marquee>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    var myMarquee = $('#myMarquee')[0]; 
    setTimeout(function() {
        myMarquee.stop();
        setTimeout(function(){
            myMarquee.start();
            run();    
        },5000);   
    },1000);
});
```

you just need to fit the time you need